# Ambiguous Column in DataFrame Join - Unable to Alias or Call

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

Getting into databricks from a SQL background and working with some dataframe samples for joining for basic transformations, and I am having issues isolating the correct dataframe.column for other transformations after the join.

For DF1, I have 3 columns: user_id, user_ts, email. For DF2, I have two columns: email, converted.

Below is how I have the logic for the join. This works and returns 5 columns; however, there are two email columns in the schema

```
df3 = (df1
       .join(df2, df1.email == df2.email, "outer")
     )
```

I am trying to do some basic transformation on the df2 email as part the dataframe string, but I receive the error:

"Cannot resolve column name "df2.email" among (user_id, user_ts, email, email, converted)"

```
df3 = (df1
       .join(df2, df1.email == df2.email, "outer")
       .na.fill(False,["df2.email"])
     )
```

If I remove the df2 from the fill(), I get the error that the columns are ambiguous.

How can I define which column I want to do a transformation on if it has the same column name as a second column. In SQL, I just use a table alias predicate for the column, but this doesn't seem to be how pyspark is bested used.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid both key columns in the join result and get combined result then you can pass list of key columns as an argument to `join()` method.

If you want to retain same key columns from both dataframes then you have to rename one of the column name before doing transformation, otherwise spark will throw ambiguous column error.

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 'abc@gmail.com'),(2,'def@gmail.com')],["id1", "email"])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 'abc@gmail.com'),(2,'ghi@gmail.com')],["id2", "email"])
df1.join(df2,['email'], 'outer').show()
'''
+-------------+----+----+
|        email| id1| id2|
+-------------+----+----+
|def@gmail.com|   2|null|
|ghi@gmail.com|null|   2|
|abc@gmail.com|   1|   1|
+-------------+----+----+'''

df1.join(df2,df1['email'] == df2['email'], 'outer').show()
'''
+----+-------------+----+-------------+
| id1|        email| id2|        email|
+----+-------------+----+-------------+
|   2|def@gmail.com|null|         null|
|null|         null|   2|ghi@gmail.com|
|   1|abc@gmail.com|   1|abc@gmail.com|
+----+-------------+----+-------------+'''

df1.join(df2,df1['email'] == df2['email'], 'outer') \
.select('id1', 'id2', df1['email'], df2['email'].alias('email2')) \
.na.fill('False','email2').show()
'''
+----+----+-------------+-------------+
| id1| id2|        email|       email2|
+----+----+-------------+-------------+
|   2|null|def@gmail.com|        False|
|null|   2|         null|ghi@gmail.com|
|   1|   1|abc@gmail.com|abc@gmail.com|
+----+----+-------------+-------------+ '''
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Mohana. Your example worked well using the select field to alias the specific column. I was also able to get working with an withColumnRenamed for the df2 as part of the join() call..